# How can I check the state of a semaphore in c?

Tags: c, ipc, pipe, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a global static variable that is a semaphore , since I'm writing a library and not a program .

Within a `main()` program that uses the library there are invokes of `fork()` , and reading & writing into/from a pipe , based on a shared memory .

For example , this is `main()` that uses my library :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my_pipe_shared_memory_based.h"
int main()

{
    int spd, pid, rb;
    char buff[4096];
    my_new_init();

    if (my_new_fifo("tmp_shm_pipe",0666) < 0)
    {
        perror("my_new_fifo");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fork()) 
    {
        spd = my_new_open("tmp_shm_pipe", O_RDONLY, 0600);
        if (spd < 0)
        {
            perror("PARENT: my_new_open");
            exit(1);
        }
        rb = my_new_read(spd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        if (rb > 0)
            write(1, buff, rb);
    }

    else
    {
        spd = my_new_open("tmp_shm_pipe", O_WRONLY, 0600);
        if (spd < 0)
        {
            perror("SON: my_new_open");
            exit(1);
        }
        my_new_write(spd, "hello world!\n", sizeof("hello world!\n"));
    }

    my_new_close(spd);
    my_new_un_link("tmp_shm_pipe");
    my_new_finish();

    return 0;
}
```

Now , I want to use a semaphore before each time that a process is **reading and/or writing** in the methods :

1. **my_new_write()**
2. **my_new_read()**

Now , the question is , how can I check the state of the semaphore each time in the requested methods above (e.g. `my_new_write` & `my_new_read`) , so I can let the process do his thing , or block it , if another process is currently reading/writing ?

Thanks

Comment: You semaphore "mySemaphore" is not visible across different processes. See my answer.

Comment: You can also simply try to replace "S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR" with "S_IRWXO" in the sem_open call. It should work, although I'm not absolutely sure :)

Comment: @JoãoFernandes: Tried that , still the output is just: `Output:` and not :`Output:hello world!` . Any other idea maybe ? thanks

Comment: Have you verified that your semaphore is being initialized correctly and also --once--, not once per process? What are the return codes for each and every one of your semaphore operations?

Comment: @SanJacinto: Yes , I doubled checked that . It starts from zero (0) and goes 1 and then back to zero . Never more than 1 or less than 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing here is that you have to make sure that the semaphore ensuring mutual exclusion is visible by both processes. To do that, you need to allocate shared memory and initialize the semaphore **before** forking. For this task you can for instance use mmap. Example (without any error checking):

```c
sem_t *sem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t),
                  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0);
```

After this, use sem_init to initialize the semaphore and make sure that the second argument, pshared, is nonzero. Manual says:

> If  pshared  is  nonzero,  then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory (see shm_open(3), mmap(2), and shmget(2)).  (Since a child created by fork(2) inherits  its  parent's  memory  mappings,  it  can also access the semaphore.)  Any process that can access the shared memory region can operate on the semaphore using sem_post(3), sem_wait(3), etc.

Finally, fork the process and use sem_wait and sem_post normally.

EDIT:

Really, try to replace this:

```c
mySemaphore = sem_open("mySemaphore", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

With this:

```c
mySemaphore = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t),
                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0);
sem_init(mySemaphore, 1, 1);
```

in function my_new_open

Comment: It seems like you are creating the shared memory region correctly, but definitely not the semaphore.

Comment: That line `sem_init(mySemaphore, 1, 1);` causes a deadlock , the program doesn't stop running . weird ..I even can't debug the code , since I'm `forking` in `main()` . I checked the `man` of `sem_init` and the last `1` (right most operand) is supposed indeed be 1 for mutual exclusion , however is still in a deadlock .

Comment: @ron, taking a better look at your code, it seems like you have other problems. For instance, reading seems nonblocking, which might be the source of your problem, because you probably want to wait until there is data available in the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the sem_trywait() and sem_wait() the things you're looking for ? Call them with the semaphore handle and you will know their state.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_trywait.html

Not sure about semaphores, but the pthread_cond_timedwait() with a mutex may also allow you to check the state of synchronization without blocking the thread (or giving the timeout).

Comment: Victor ,I tried them already (the threads , I mean) .And now I tried with `sem_wait` & `sem_post` but the code is still not synchronized . Any idea idea ? should I post the code maybe ? thanks

Comment: Definitely, post the read/write functions and we'll have a look.

Comment: Done , I posted 3 methods : `open` , `read` , and `write` .thanks .